# configure multiple different external activemq för wildfly

Tags: activemq-classic, wildfly-10

Is it possible to configure multiple external activemq for wildfly? I have two external activemq that runs on different port and url, can I configure them for one wildfly?

Comment: Can you clarify your use-case? Do you have applications on Wildfly that need to consume messages from or sent messages to (or both) your external ActiveMQ brokers? Do you use MDBs? Are the external brokers ActiveMQ 5.x or ActiveMQ Artemis? Do you want to use the JCA resource adapter to integrate with the external ActiveMQ brokers?

Comment: ActiveMq 5, I need to access too two different external ActiveMQ server running on different url and port. I was using mdb för one cluster before

Comment: In your previous configuration when you were using an MDB to consume messages from a cluster how were you doing that? I assume you had configured the ActiveMQ JCA resource adapter in the Wildfly XML. Is that correct?